# Create TS interface with a dynamic number of dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, react-typescript

I need to create an interface that has a dynamic number of keys, with dynamic key values.

eg:
the object could look like

```
{
  email: string
  password: string
}
```

or

```
{
  age: string
  occupation: string
  height: string
}
```

and so on...

These object keys will be generated dynamically from a list of objects `fields` where `fields: Field[]` and

```
interface Field {
  name: string
  label: string
  type: string
  styles?: FieldStyles
}
```

basically using the `name` key/value from the list of `Field`'s to set the keys on this new interface. (In this example case, the values of these dynamically set keys will always be of type `string` because they represent form inputs of type `text`, `email`, & `password`. All of which correspond to `string` types in JS)

I am trying to create an object like this

```
const defaultFormState: any = {}
  props.fields.forEach((field) => {
    defaultFormState[field.name] = ''
  })
```

but right now I have to use the `any` on `defaultFormState` to satisfy TypeScript and obviously, I want to avoid this.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What's the type of `FieldStyles`?

Comment: You also said "dynamically" - so will the `props.fields` be known for sure at compile time?

Comment: Ok, but again, you said you would get these keys "dynamically". Are we talking at runtime, or what?

Comment: `interface FieldStyles {
  label?: string
  name?: string
  wrapper?: string
}`

But it's not relevant to the question because it's not being used to create the `defaultFormState`. Probably better just to remove it from the question to avoid confusion...

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, yes. These keys will be available at run time. A parent component will pass the down as hard-coded props.

Comment: I think you should just use `{ [key: string]: string }` as the type of `defaultFormState`. Making it match the given type of `fields` doesn't have any benefit in the component implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is an XY problem, but here it is using types not interface

```
type LiteralInterface<Obj> = {
  [K in keyof Obj]: Obj[K] extends string
    ? string
    : Obj[K] extends number
    ? number
    : Obj[K] extends boolean
    ? boolean
    : Obj[K];
};
```

How to use

```
type myInterface = LiteralInterface<typeof { prop: "hi", prop2: 42 }>
```

After reading your comment, I realized you might be wanting this

```
type PropertyValueIsString = {
  [K in string]: string;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the `[K in string]...` and the TS errors went away. They TS errors also when away when I implemented the solution to  @caTS suggested in the comment above: `{ [key: string]: string }`. So both seem to work. Is one better than the other?

Comment: Are these two equivelent?